# How can equilibrium weights be found for momentum factor in Black-Litterman model?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, black-litterman

I have a momentum factor which consists of going long in three rising ETFs and going short in three falling ETFs. I want to use this factor as part of my portfolio for Black-Litterman model, however I do not understand how I can come up with equilibrium weights for this kind of factors.

What would be the right strategy here?